# Failed to activate Schematics on ArcGIS for Server?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, arcgis-license-manager, schematics

I am trying to activate Schematics in ArcGIS 10.2 for Server's Capabilities.

After I click "Save and Restart" button, it throw an error message :

> Schematic Server Extension is not supported with the current license.

Here's a screenshot for ArcGIS Server Software Authorization.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a good chance you don't have the Schematics extension licensed for your server (or it was expired recently). Go to the AGS Manager web page at `https://localhost:6443/arcgis/manager/authorization.html` and see if Schematics is in the list there.

Alternatively, take a look at the keycodes file located at the `C:\Program Files\ESRI\License10.3\sysgen` folder; there should be a `schematicssvr` post inside.

Answer (score 1):

Per this [posted solution](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/83302) to an identical problem on GeoNet, contacting ESRI support will likely get your Server license problems resolved fastest.  You didn't do anything wrong, and they'll straighten your licensing problem up.

Answer (score 0):

If you do have a license for Schematics, you may need to enable it.

- Log in to ArcGIS Server Manager and click Site.

  Click Extensions > Add Extension.

  Click Browse and browse to the .soe file.

  Click Add.

Resource:  [This tutorial from ESRI](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/linux/deploying-an-extension.htm)

Comment: -1 as the link in this answer is for Desktop licensing of the Schematics extension, while the question is about Server extension licensing.

Comment: @JasonInVegas Good catch--no idea what I was doing that day. I have updated with instructions for server.